# generate unique voucher/code for every customer/user

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, data-modeling, laravel-5.6

i try to build website like **grou**, which is a platform to sell vouchers for some items in merchants.

The `customer` or `user` can buy `vouchers` and **redeem** it at an offline store (or merchants) based on the `vouchers` they've bought.

I confused about logic or database design about redeem the voucher. What I want to ask :

1. How to generate a unique code for every **coupon/voucher** that `users` have bought. Every voucher that has been posted on a website has primary key. If **10 customer** bought the same voucher, how to avoid duplication when they redeem it. If i add **unique code**, should I add in `vouchers` table or I generate it after `users` checkout.
2. Should I make table for redemption and redemption detail. And how to give a sign if that voucher had been used.

Please give me some advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First problem**

You can use voucher ID and for example user ID. So if we have 2 users and 1 voucher then this unique codes will be like this: 1-1, 1-2.

If they will look like 1-1 and 1-2 then with simple explode on `-` mark you will have two elements array where first will be voucher ID, and second will be User ID. You can store it in vouchers table...

But a better approach will be if you will use many to many relations. You are creating `Users`, `Vouchers`, and `UserVouchers` tables and connect functions between them. User can have many userVouchers, but userVoucher have only one voucher. Look at my pickup db: http://www.laravelsd.com/share/8O0xtZ. This is called pivot and you are creating it when you are connecting user with voucher.

**Second problem**

From `UserVoucher` relation you will have how many times this voucher has been used. You need to only have a column in Vouchers table, for example `max_users` and if you write there for example 4 you need to prevent creating new interaction if you have 4 rows in `UserVoucher` or at frontend you can check this and don't show buy button. Both secured ways will be good ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look into a [many to many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) between the `users` and `vouchers` tables/models. This basically means that many `users` can have many `vouchers` and vice versa.

The table can then have other fields such as `redeemed` (which could be a `dateTime` field) and `notes`/`details`. Having `redeemed` as a dateTime field means you can set the exact time the `user` redeemed this voucher.

This can be used so that the `user` does not redeem the voucher several times over.